# In php can I loop a database update while getting variables from url?

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, sql-update

**This is in a php webpage**

I have a link coming in as `www.example.com/add_new.php?code=1234[]&code=4321[]&code=4263[]&attend=1` I need to update the database for `code` mark attend as `attend="1"` I can get it to work if I just have one. But when I have more than one can I loop this to edit all values?

```
$codes = $_GET['code'];
foreach ($codes as $code) {
$sql = "UPDATE guests SET attend='$isattend' WHERE code=$add";
}
```

what is the correct syntax for this?

Right Now it only applies the last on `code=4263[]` and marks `4263 as attend=1` but I need `foreach`

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you try it? right after you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php Otherwise, enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Why not create a string that you have concatenated from the $_GET['code']? That way you don't have to keep accessing the DB

Answer (score 2):

With query string like `?code=1234&code=4321&code=4263&attend=1` your `code` value will be `4263`. Cause previous value is overwritten by the following.
For passing several codes in a query string you should use `[]`:

```
?code[]=1234&code[]=4321&code[]=4263&attend=1
```

Then in `$_GET['code']` you will have an array:

```
$codes = $_GET['code'];
// also you can check if $codes is array with `is_array` function
foreach ($codes as $code) {
    // do some database related stuff
    $sql = "UPDATE guests SET attend='$isattend' WHERE code=$add";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to note the SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. If you have an array of items that you want to update, you would loop over them and execute an update query. There's a lot of things in your response that makes me think you should take a step back and review the basics.

First, a foreach loop looks something like this:

```
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        //do something
    }
```

Next, you really really don't want to write SQL queries like you're doing. It's a bad idea because people can take advantage of your code and attack you via **SQL Injection**

To prevent this, you can use a library that comes with PHP called PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

You will use something called a prepared statement that will let you design an SQL query and then inject values into it, and it helps prevent all of the scary injection attacks. For example, yours might look like

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE guests SET attend=:attend WHERE code=:code");
$stmt->bindParam(':attend', $attend);
$stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to implement this advice. Good luck!

Comment: Would using `settype($offset, 'integer');` be enough to protect it?

Comment: I just don't understand what `$stmt = $pd` is. And what does `code=:code` repeating it through a `:` do? Thanks